# Cannot filter search result on custom post type

Tags: full-site-editing

I am not sure how to put this question, but I am trying to explain it.

I created a WordPress block theme which has a search module. The keyword-based search returns expected result without any issue. On search result page, I have a filter dropdown which holds the post types including the custom post types.

I have Cool Timeline Pro plugin installed in my system. Every timeline story creates a post of type cool_timeline. This is included in the above mentioned dropdown as well.

By default, the search result combines all existing post types. When I filter the search result by selecting any one post type from the dropdown, the result gets filtered and the it shows only the posts from the selected post type.

Now, when I select cool_timeline (or, Timeline Stories), the search page jumps back site's homepage. This is happening only for cool_timeline post type.

[image]

When I am selecting Timeline Stories, although there are posts available, the page still jumps back to the home page instead of filtering it off and display on search result screen. I tested the basic configuan o